# Show all searched location result on google map

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

i m creating a web application using Google map in it. i need to know how to implement, when i m searching some location using php and i get the result in php array(), that array result which contains different location's coordinates(latitude longitude) display on map + focuses on these coordinates in a map view .....

Comment: Want to focus them all together, or one by one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a GBound and give it all your points at creation on later using extend() method.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference#GBounds

Then use the map.fitBounds() method to set the view on these points.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Comment: This is the best reference for using GBound....
Thanks

This link helps me more
http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.com/2011/03/zoom-to-fit-all-markers-on-google-map.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the map to scroll, use the Google Static Maps API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Add an `<img>` tag to your HTML, with a source in the following format:
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=LAT,LONG&amp;zoom=14&amp;size=288x200&amp;sensor=false"`

This will return a map image centred on the co-ordinates you have specified.

Comment: Then look at the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). A basic introduction is on that page.